# Google Maps rtl on mobile gives horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, android, css, google-maps, google-chrome

When I'm trying to use Google Maps on mobile with dir:rtl I get an horizontal scroll bar instead of having full wide map and my page becomes wider than the screen.
I've also tried using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Didn't help.

Even if I'm using Google's sample it happens. Changing the direction to ltr shows how I expect it to be.

[Google's rtl sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-rtl)
If you copy the code from Try it yourself you'll get the issue too.

Thank you,
Chen

Comment: The examples work fine on my mobile. What is your environment?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your map is width:100%; so it's not wider than the browser.

You can fix the horizontal scroll by adding the following CSS:

```
html,
body {
   overflow-x:hidden;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```